# Can Custom Post Types be used as the Post Author (in Wordpress)?

Tags: wordpress, author

Here is the normal Wordpress functionality: All the "Author" and "Contributor" roles under Users are available to select as the Author of a new Post.

I want to create a Custom Post Type, called "Faculty", that contains more than just Authors (webinar speakers too). Not just so we can get all Faculty in one place, but also because I think that the interface for adding a person to a CPT is much better than dealing with adding/editing a person through the Users section.

When we go to create a new post, I want to see all the people under the "Faculty" CPT in the Author area and be able to select one of them as the author of the post, instead of the default list of Authors/Contributors.

Is this possible? With or without a plugin, I don't care. I found a lot of articles about adding authors to custom post types, but nothing about selecting a CPT as the author of a post.

Comment: We currently have the Advanced Custom Fields, User Role Editor and Co-Authors Plus plugins running...in case any of those can be utilized, but also because we do try to support co-authors on our posts as well.

Comment: the `post_author` is a specific relative field in the database that links to a user by their ID.  What I would do is create a user each time a "Faculty CPT" is created. That way you have a User ID and you can pull their data from the the CPT based on the author_id of that post. Kinda gives you the benefit of both.

Comment: Why not use a custom taxonomy where you would enter term as author, like that you could have also some type of hierarchy, then affect the custom taxonomy to whatever post/page or else ?

Comment: Then you could change the visual aspect of the checkboxes to a dropdown, for an easier management. Or just leave the checkboxes to be able to add multiple author to a post. You could also set up so kind of default author. That's a more straight forward approach, at least that's my take on it.

Comment: Tho, with this method, articles wouldn't be assign to a specific user. But you could still have specific page for each so called "author" as it's a taxonomy. It would be mostly a front end feature, with no real backend management beside default taxonomy management options.

Comment: These are both good ideas/workarounds, thank you. I think I can figure out a solution based on one of these, for sure.